# how to regenerate android resource file (R.java) with working on Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, r.java-file

I need to regenerate the resource file, I did these steps but it could not help.

1. right click on the project
2. click to force regenerate R.java file

to clean the project was a solution on eclipse but I just started to develope a project on intellij and dont find any solution. anyone knows how do I regenerate the source file on intellij?

Comment: I don't know about intellij but on eclipse having errors in your xml files stopped R.java from regenerating...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intellij version of "clean" is called "Rebuild Project". It's in the Build menu.

Comment: I tried the mentioned solution but it didn't work, but then i changed the package in manifest and tried to rebuild project and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that work.

- go to gen/ and delete R.java
- go to gen/R.java and correct the package name. check the other files in gen/ also.

In IntelliJ, the function "Rebuild Project" is not the same as Eclipse's "clean project".

The accepted answer (rebuild project) by toadsky is not correct in all cases.

Rebuild project does not necessarily regenerate the R.java resources. I observed this directly after renaming a package in IntelliJ. I had only the R error, after searching through all my resources and seeing that all files had the new package name. Rebuilding didnt fix it and then i noticed that the generated files had not been rewritten and had the old package name. The quick solution was to rename the package in the generated files, and the error went away.

changing any xml file , or the manifest file, didnt trigger a regeneration as i had read.

When i had this issue and looked at the gen/R.java file, i saw that it had a list of resources that was way out of date. however, correcting the package name on this out-of-date file immediately fixed the R error.

When i deleted the R.java containing the obsolete R list and old package name, it also fixed the problem. IntelliJ immediately generated a new R.java file that didnt contain any resources, and there was no R error.